# How do i connect java socket client to multiple servers

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, distributed

I'm trying to connect client to more than 1 server Ex:4 servers to divide data in client side on servers number then send them to servers and get the result (distributed System)

Comment: Create another socket that connects to the other server

Comment: have you tried something ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.   One socket per connection.    Have your client make multiple sockets if you want to connect to multiple servers - you could then either multiplex these using an nio Selector, or use a thread-per-connection model to marshal data messages to a client controller.

Here's a good intro to network programming (most of the concepts carry over directly to Java):  [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html)

There's also: [The Java Networking Basics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html)

Comment: To add one quick comment, you technically can if you use UDP (one socket, multiple endpoints), but it will change your protocols somewhat and you will still need to do your own multiplexing/channelization.

Comment: Ah, shoot, yeah, I was assuming TCP.   Thanks for the correction!